# Typescript Record like type, but implicit value

Tags: typescript, record, implicit

Is it possible to tell typescript I don't want to set value type, so it can deduce it later based on scenario, but in the meantime I want to restrict keys?

My approach was to use Record, cause it was really close to reach my goal, but what I really want to do is something like this:

```
type Lang = 'pl' | 'en';
type AllRoutes = Record<Lang, [implicit type]> // would be awesome to do something like this

// some const strings
const plRoutes = {...};
const enRoutes = {...};
export const allRoutes: AllRoutes  = {
  en: enRoutes,
  pl: plRoutes,
};
```

When I don't add AllRotues type to allRoutes then typescript knows value types very nicely, but i can add as many keys as I want. I should be restricted

### Update

```
type Lang = 'pl' | 'en';
// some const strings
const plRoutes = {...};
const enRoutes = {...};
type AllRoutes = Record<Lang, typeof plRoutes | typeof enRoutes> 


export const allRoutes: AllRoutes  = {
  en: enRoutes,
  pl: plRoutes,
};
```

The above would work, but I was hoping for nicer solution where we are not forced to write typeof xRoute | zRoute.... It would be pitifull on multiple language.

Answer (score 1):

You could be using generics :

```
type Lang = 'pl' | 'en';
type AllRoutes<V> = Record<Lang, V>

// some const strings
const plRoutes = { a: 'a', b: 3 };
const enRoutes = { c: {} };
export const allRoutes: AllRoutes<typeof plRoutes | typeof enRoutes> = {
    en: enRoutes,
    pl: plRoutes,
};
```

or if you have a common interface

```
interface language { a: string, b: number };

const plRoutes: language = { a: 'a', b: 1 };
const enRoutes: language = { a: 'b', b: 2 };
export const allRoutes: AllRoutes<language> = {
    en: enRoutes,
    pl: plRoutes,
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=3&pln=12&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAMghgOwOZQLxQORgDYagH0wgQwG4AoUSKAQW2wCUB7AV2AgGcAeANQD40UBhADGTAE4ATLvGQAaKPygB6ZVADurbJKgAjaHHWcmAW2jAmUSZY6mIwABYBLZFGxOA1uecdy5VVC2ZlBiCBzAgcDiLki%20oeFQOMxsnIIA3lBwAFyYcBgKujkAzFAAvhTxEcTJ7BzpITlppWUUEAAeYBIRlZn0NZw5dIystVxUEEwAZonDKXWE41NQ1SOcAuhp5FDbywg5K3NyWzs4OUmrHEflfi7s4pNwItDYiEgscEjQGdmR0fJ6OQQLBM%20nELT8PXOcwATDkXsh3p96j8MHkCjkAIzgnoHWqwtyvRHQDaZHIYXT5AFQaHg9qdcTdJhhCJwPoXfFDfrceFvD4QdZQTY7Xb7BBc6FHYWnGbiq6kIA)

Comment: I have common interface, but only for keys, cause value are const strings (not generic string) so only first solution would work. I was hoping that we can somehow tell typescript to calculate value on its own. This way It would be easier to add new language in the future and "typeof plRoutes | typeof enRoutes | ..." doesnt look good. I will go with this solution for now.

Answer (score 0):

If I got your question right, I suggest using generics so you can do something like this (note that you still need to tell TS what your type is when you use the AllRoutes type):

```js
type Lang = 'pl' | 'en';
type AllRoutes<T> = Record<Lang, T>

export const allRoutes: AllRoutes<[the type of your routes]>  = {
...
};
```

However, I think it will be much simpler to use an interface or type if you only want to restrict the keys.

```js
type Routes = {
  [key in Lang]: [your type here];
};

// or
interface IRoutes {
 en: [your type here],
 pl: [your type here]
}
```